# BigQuery Convert Columns to RECORD

Tags: arrays, google-bigquery, record

In BigQuery, How can I turn many columns into a RECORD or Array of Key Value pairs
e.g.

Source Table

| id | Name | DOB | Sex |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Fred | 01.01.2001 | M |

Destination Table

| Id | Name | Key | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Fred | DOB | 01.01.2001 |
|  |  | Sex | M |

I've tried a few things but cant get there, is there a nice way of doing it?

Answer (score 1):

> I've tried a few things but cant get there, is there a nice way of doing it?

Not sure what exactly was /could be an issue here as it is as simple/straightforward as below

```
select id, Name,
  [struct<key string, value string>('DOB', DOB),('Sex', Sex)] info
from `project.dataset.table`
```

with output

[image]

Meantime, usually the issue comes when you don't know those columns names in advance and want to have generic approach - in this case you can use below approach where column names `DOB` and `Sex` are not being used

```
select id, Name,
  array(
    select as struct
      split(replace(kv, '"', ''),':')[offset(0)] key, 
      split(replace(kv, '"', ''),':')[offset(1)] value, 
    from unnest(split(trim(to_json_string((select as struct * except (id, name) from unnest([t]))), '{}'))) kv
  ) info
from `project.dataset.table` t
```

with exact same result/output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution:-

```
WITH `proj.dataset.tbl` AS
(SELECT '1' AS id, 'Fred' AS Name, '2020-12-07' AS DOB, 'M' as Sex
)
SELECT id, Name,
        [struct('DOB' as key, cast (DOB as string) as value ),
        struct('Sex' as key, Sex as value)
       ] as key_values

FROM `proj.dataset.tbl`
```

Output will be as :-

[image]